# How to monitor if a network connection is stable during the day

Tags: networking

We have a mysql server working on Ubuntu server.

Many clients (using a Windows Xp app) give us the "Lost connection to MySQL server during query".

How can I track down the problem?

The server is always fully functional and I don't have any diagnostic idea.
The server is sitting on a VmWare ESXi and has always worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `icpld` from http://icpld.northernmost.org

ICPLD is a connection monitor which allows you to keep track of your network connection perfomance. It will log each occasion of broken networking. It runs as a background process, and sends ICMP requests to an ip of your choice. When a reply isn't received within proper amount of time, it will consider the connection as unavailable and put a stamp in its log.

Answer (score 1):

You could look in `/var/log/mysql.* /var/log/mysql/error.log` to see if your server has anything to say about daytime activities.

You could also come up with a simple MySQL transaction that you could run periodically to check response time.

You could adapt [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665721/how-to-rotate-wifi-connections/665755#665755) to maintain connectivity