# Is there a way for ubuntu to automatically switch wifi signals?

Tags: wireless

I sometimes use my laptop in my house, and depending which part of the house I am in, I will have a weaker or stronger signal from either fo the routers/access points.

Is there a way to have Ubuntu switch to the stronger signal?

Can this be configured in Ubuntu?

Thanks

Joseph

Comment: It's not related to ubuntu, you should config your router/access point to use the highest signal that it capable of.

Comment: @Ravexina that doesn't at all answer the question, which was "Is there a way to have Ubuntu switch to the stronger signal [out of two access points]?" It's also not a particularly good idea to have an access point's transmission range greatly exceed the computer's transmission range, both because that leads to zones where the computer sees an access point but can't connect to it or can only connect to it with a lot of lost transmissions and because it causes useless interference with WiFi access points of even more of your neighbors than necessary.

Comment: @Chai T. Rex, +1. You're right, I didn't understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wait until the weakening signal fails (the connection drops), my answer at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665721/how-to-rotate-wifi-connections/665755#665755) will help