# Wireless Frequently Disconnects Across Multiple Wifi Networks

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, intel-wireless

My wireless frequently disconnects, both on my home wireless and at work.

I ran the [wireless diagnostic tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) that I've seen other user's recommend; my results are posted [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24462141/).

Any magic bullets for me?

Comment: I do not think it is related to Ubuntu or drivers. I have the same wireless adapter and the same system. The adapter works well.

Comment: huh. Any thoughts on what it could be, then?

Comment: No specific thoughts. It may be a hardware problem, like a bad antenna contact, or some radio interference, etc. It is hard to guess.

Comment: You could adapt my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665721/how-to-rotate-wifi-connections) to Do Something when WiFi drops