# Constantly disconnected from wireless internet | Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, internet

i've got my system working as Dual Booted with Windows. But only on Ubuntu i have the problem that my Wifi keeps disconnecting. I don't have access for an internet cable so i need a solution without that.

I boot up Ubuntu and everything works fine, but when i start launching applications and such i keep getting disconnected. I don't know if it is one of my programs interfering with my wifi.

I've tried different ways of fixing this solution. Here is a log i got from running a piece of code:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 03 Jun 2017 15:24 CEST +0200

Booted last: 03 Jun 2017 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.0-21-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 28 16:14:22 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:8554]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2161]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0005 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 192f:0916 Avago Technologies, Pte. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0184 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5182 Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3414 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1532:0040 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1532:0203 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

eeepc_wmi              16384  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
rtl8821ae             225280  0
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8821ae
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8821ae
rtlwifi                73728  2 rtl_pci,rtl8821ae
mac80211              782336  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8821ae
cfg80211              602112  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
wmi                    16384  1 asus_wmi
video                  40960  1 asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.190/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlp4s0
       valid_lft 86343sec preferred_lft 86343sec
    inet6 fe80::3da8:bc31:4f77:6088/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Milan 5GHZ"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]>   
          Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=23 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:3   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 proto static metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp4s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.190 metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1118     1  0 15:20 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8821ae
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.10.0-21-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:04:00.0/net/wlp4s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp4s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Milan 5GHZ
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       ab6af6f3-b5c6-4853-a2a7-d8215510cc0e
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     150 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ab6af6f3-b5c6-4853-a2a7-d8215510cc0e | Milan 5GHZ
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.190/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.190
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       wpad = a
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1496582593
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       host_name = olle-G10AC
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::3da8:bc31:4f77:6088/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID                        BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 
comhem_55B12C               <MAC 'comhem_55B12C' [AN1]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2      no        
Milan 2.4GHz                <MAC 'Milan 2.4GHz' [AN2]>  Infra  10    2457 MHz  54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2      no        
comhem_55B12C-5G            <MAC 'comhem_55B12C-5G' [AN3]>  Infra  100   5500 MHz  54 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      no        
--                          <MAC '--' [AN4]>  Infra  161   5805 MHz  0 Mbit/s   70      ▂▄▆_  WEP       no        
comhem_011C2B               <MAC 'comhem_011C2B' [AN5]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      no        
Milan 5GHZ                  <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]>  Infra  48    5240 MHz  54 Mbit/s  63      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      yes     * 
SpeedTouch1112DE            <MAC 'SpeedTouch1112DE' [AN7]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WEP       no        
HP-Print-41-Officejet 6700  <MAC 'HP-Print-41-Officejet 6700' [AN8]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA2      no        
--                          <MAC '--' [AN9]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  --        no        
comhem_EAA94A               <MAC 'comhem_EAA94A' [AN10]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2      no        
--                          <MAC '--' [AN11]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  --        no        
Sundgren                    <MAC 'Sundgren' [AN12]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA2      no        
comhem_691B03               <MAC 'comhem_691B03' [AN13]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  WPA2      no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Milan 5GHZ]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Milan 5GHZ | type=wifi | permissions=user:olle:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Milan 5GHZ
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Stockholm (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp3s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp4s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)

##### iwlist scan #######################

wlp4s0    Failed to read scan data : Resource temporarily unavailable

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8821ae]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw.bin
description:    Realtek 8821ae 802.11ac PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     7035D4BEF647A4E63CBD578
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           int_clear:Set to 0 to disable interrupt clear before set (default 1)
 (bool)

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     B93F82B28F7945C22514E4D
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload 

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     884DE3F31278351A45DA409
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-21-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     25AD08C8BBFD528CC9B45E2
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-21-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D77C8F93375950F3BA95B16
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8821ae]
debug: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: Y
int_clear: Y
ips: Y
msi: Y
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   18.616718] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin
[   18.655666] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin failed with error -2
[   18.655668] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin
[   18.655670] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin
[   19.117676] rtl8821ae 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[   19.131092] rtl8821ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw.bin
[   19.131094] rtl8821ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_wowlan.bin
[   19.374443] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   19.374634] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   19.375866] rtl8821ae 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[   21.901184] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   22.051361] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[   22.051408] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   22.053494] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready (repeated 5 times)
[   25.983130] wlp4s0: authenticate with <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]>
[   25.983486] wlp4s0: send auth to <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]> (try 1/3)
[   25.984027] wlp4s0: authenticated
[   25.984511] wlp4s0: associate with <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]> (try 1/3)
[   25.985308] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=5)
[   25.988068] wlp4s0: associated
[   25.988080] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[   26.074607] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]>
[  160.715753] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  185.767107] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  185.953482] wlp4s0: authenticate with <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]>
[  185.953802] wlp4s0: send auth to <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]> (try 1/3)
[  185.954323] wlp4s0: authenticated
[  185.959483] wlp4s0: associate with <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]> (try 1/3)
[  185.960290] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=5)
[  185.963043] wlp4s0: associated
[  185.963082] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[  186.123557] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'Milan 5GHZ' [AN6]>

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: You could use my `net-o-matic` script from https://askubuntu.com/questions/665721/how-to-rotate-wifi-connections to find the exact time your WiFi drops, and use `journalctl --since "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" --until "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"`, filling in the exact time minus 30 seconds and plus 30 seconds to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The key detail in your problem report might be that your network device is RTL8111/8168/8411.

There appears to be issues in 17.04 because the correct mod isn't included in the distribution.

To check if you are affected do:

```
lshw -class network | grep RTL8111/8168/8411    
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 (...)                 # (1)
lsmod |grep r8169                               
r8169                  81920  0                  # (2)
```

(1) indicates your hardware is RTL8168

(2) indicates your driver is r8169

This is not a compatible combination, because the 8169 driver doesn't work properly with 8168 hardware

To fix this you need to install dkms & r8168-dkms.

If you are lucky and have a temporary spell of Internet access then do:

```
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
```

Otherwise you will have to check if dkms is installed (3) and then install the driver (4) by getting it onto your system and directly using "dpkg -i". If dkms isn't installed then there is probably going to be a fair few things to install.

```
dpkg -l | grep dkms                             # (3)
ii  dkms                                        2.3-3ubuntu1 (...)
dpkg -i r8168-dkms_8.043.02-1_all.deb           # (4)
```

I hope this solves your problem.

A more detailed description can be found @ [HOWTO: RTL8168](https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/)